# RelativeLayout and 2 Fragments dividing the screen - No weights or LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an android app, which currently uses 1 activity only, in landscape mode only, `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"`

I want fragment 1 to take 50% of the space of RelativeLayout, (that means 50% of the parent RelativeLayout width and height). Same with fragment 2.
I heard using weights is not advisable as it might cause performance issues.

This is what I want:
[image]

This is my code (ignore the 40dp values):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainPreviewActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp">
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using LinearLayout and `layout_weight`. It _may_ become a problem if you have nested weights and a deeper view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could have **configChanges="orientation|screenSize"** in your **AndroidManifest.xml**, use a `FrameLayout` as root and handle re-sizing yourself in **onConfigurationChanged** of your activity. That way you'll be in control on what happens during a resize/rotate.

To me that seems an over-kill, though. I would simply go for `LinearLayout` and `layout_weight` as suggested in the previous comment. For such a simple layout there shouldn't be any performance issues. That depends, of course, on the complexity of your fragments' layouts.

Answer (score 2):

1. I'm not sure what performance issues you will get, but a `LinearLayout` and `layout_weight` is a very good solution for this.
2. You can also try to get the screen width and set the `LayoutParams` for the fragments according to this.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an easier way. These are just suggestions :P

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainPreviewActivity">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1">
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want use RelativeLayout anyway, you can put empty view into the center of this layout. One fragment should be toLeft of this view, and another toRight